# com.mysql.jdbc.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure (glassfish+mysql))

Tags: java, mysql, glassfish-3

We are using glassfish-3.1.2.18 with java 1.8.0_161 and mysql. The application gets hung periodically(say every 2 months). we could see this error in the logs

=============================================================================
Last packet sent to the server was 6 ms ago.

STACKTRACE:

com.mysql.jdbc.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure due to underlying exception:

** BEGIN NESTED EXCEPTION **

java.io.EOFException
MESSAGE: Can not read response from server. Expected to read 4 bytes, read 0 bytes before connection was unexpectedly lost.

STACKTRACE:

java.io.EOFException: Can not read response from server. Expected to read 4 bytes, read 0 bytes before connection was unexpectedly lost.
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readFully(MysqlIO.java:1997)

=====================================================================

Finally it ends up in

====================================================================

## java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Can any one help me how to debug?
I can't see any problem in our code that can cause connection leak.

Some background info : We use jdbc connection which received from jdbc connection pool in glassfish.

Issue starts in quartz job that runs in background.

Heap space error stack:

org.quartz.SchedulerException: 
Job threw an unhandled exception. [See nested exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space]
at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:227)
at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:549)
Caused by:
 java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Comment: `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space` means, that the JVM run out of memory. This comes up when you have a memory leak or create a big object. In your case this seems to be a problem with the mysql connector that tries to create such a huge object.

Comment: How can i avoid this situation? how to say mysql connector not to create huge objects?

Comment: I'm not sure about it. I think it is because it tries to connect with the MySQL Server and rescieves a response that is not long anough. Maybe it would help if you post the StackTrace of the OutOfMemoryError. This could show in what method and class the Object is created.

Comment: The logs show nothing?